# Polynomial interpolation in quotient polynomial ring

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, interpolation

I would really appreciate help in this question, or even a good direction for an answer. I have looked in the appropriate literature without much progress..

**Q1:**

Let $p(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\omega\in\mathbb{C}$, and let $\mathcal{R}$ be the quotient polynomial ring over the ideal created by $p(x)$ $$\mathcal{R}=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$$
For a given polynomial $q(x)\in\mathcal{R}$, given $q(\omega)$, what is $q(x)$? is there a closed formula to find $q(x)$ in $\mathcal{R}$?

It is easy to see that $q(x)$ is uniquely determined by the value $q(\omega)$ (if $q_1(\omega)=q_2(\omega)$ their difference is the $0\in\mathcal{R}$ polynomial)

**Example**

Even for small rank polynomials I am not sure what to do, for example when $p(x)=x^4+1$ is the minimal polynomial of the 8th root of unity $exp(\frac{2\pi i}{8})$.

**Naive attempt**

The Lagrange Polynomial could provide the correct polynomial, but it is not in the ring if the coefficients are complex and not rational.

**Q2:**

The real answer that I am after is for the general case where $p(x)$ is reducible. For example when $p(x)=x^n-1$, then if $$p(x)=\prod_{i=1}^dp_i(x)$$ for different minimal polynomials for the roots $\{\omega_1,\dots,\omega_d\}$ with $\mathcal{R}$ defined as before, then what is $q(x)$ given $\{q(\omega_1),\dots,q(\omega_d)\}$? is there a closed formula? (it is easy to see that also here $q$ is uniquely defined.)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Well for instance by the First Isomorphism Theorem, if $p(x)=x^4+1$ then $\mathbb{Q}[x] \backslash (p(x)) \sim \mathbb{Q}[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{8}}]$. This is a field and we know the structure of this field.

Comment: Thank you Rachid, yes I have not mentioned it. How does that help in this case?